# How can i populate data from a reference node into another content type in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, entityreference, nodereference

I using drupal 7 and i need some ideas for this problem.
I have two content types. hospitals and referral form. I would like to pull data from the hospital form automatically, example hospital name, address, contact etc when the user fills in the name of the hospital in the referral form.

I have used entity reference but i cant get it to work. It only gets the URL of the node but not the other fields. And also i have used autofill but it only works for a single content type. If any one has done this before or if anyone has an idea, please do help. looking forward to your responses.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to configure the Entityreference autofill module to suit my needs.